Nextjs/Typescript - recreation of scroll and mouse events
I am trying to recreate a demo template https://az-black.webflow.io/ that uses scroll effects and mouse location tracking in nextjs/typescript.
I've not seen any examples of how to properly recreate these actions - and I am unsure how to manipulate the styles/dom to recreate the effect correctly.
In this section - the two components here parallax left/right - side by side on mouse move - on load there is title animation where the text is large, then shrinks, then resumes into its current place

I've started creating a function that can manipulate these elements - but how to bind it and animate it correctly against mouse events
  React.useEffect(() => {
    //document.querySelectorAll('[data-fill]').forEach(elem => {
    //  elem.style.width = elem.getAttribute("data-fill");
    //});

    var heroTextHolder = document.querySelector(".hero-section-text-holder");
    heroTextHolder.style.transform =
      "translate3d(-0.6788px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg)";
    heroTextHolder.style["transform-style"] = "preserve-3d";
  }, []);

  //hero-section-text-holder
  //will-change: transform; transform: translate3d(-0.6788px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d;

  //hero-text-holder
  //will-change: transform; transform: translate3d(4.168px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d;

  //01 hero-text-blur
  //opacity: 0.6; filter: blur(120px); will-change: transform; transform: translate3d(-19.198px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d;

  //02 hero-text-blur
  //opacity: 0.6; filter: blur(120px); will-change: transform; transform: translate3d(-21.177px, 0px, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d;

  //iphone-holder
  //transform: translate3d(0px, 0%, 0px) scale3d(1, 1, 1) rotateX(0deg) rotateY(0deg) rotateZ(0deg) skew(0deg, 0deg); transform-style: preserve-3d; opacity: 1;

In this section where the grid is -- the edges of the focused block morph in 3d space - further away from you - there is also a kind of spotlight that follows the mouse

This part - the icons also fall into 3d space when focused on - and the phone scrolls in parallax -

There is a sticky section here -- that transforms to a white version - when scrolling - I am unsure how this scroll effect is achieved - by modifying one of the dom elements, but how to recreate this functionality in vanilla js

There are similar falling away from 3d space on mouseover on some of these icons/parts

I just made a sandbox and the code general markup and css render - but its the implementation and making of these mouse and scroll effects I'd like to implement.
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/fervent-fast-forked-2pgsdn?file=%2Fsrc%2FHero%2FHero.tsx
https://2pgsdn.csb.app/
